# C# compiler can collapse a function that returns constant?

Tags: c#, compilation

Here's a program I used to test with `BenchmarkDotNet`. I was comparing the performance of `out` vs tuple.

```
public class OutVsTuple
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void Out()
    {
        void OutLocal(out int a, out int b)
        {
            a = 1;
            b = 2;
        }

        OutLocal(out int x, out int y);
        int z = x + y;
    } 

    [Benchmark]
    public void Tuple()
    {
        (int a, int b) TupleLocal() => (1,2);

        (int x, int y) = TupleLocal();
        int z = x + y;
    } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<OutVsTuple>();
    }
}
```

Results :

```
 Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |    Median |
------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
    Out | 0.0000 ns | 0.0000 ns | 0.0000 ns | 0.0000 ns |
  Tuple | 5.3041 ns | 0.1422 ns | 0.3209 ns | 5.1754 ns |
```

I think the time for `Out` is 0.0000 because the whole function's result can be known and that makes the method meaningless. I change it around to use `Random` like this.

```
public class OutVsTuple
{
    System.Random r = new System.Random();

    [Benchmark]
    public void Out()
    {
        void OutLocal(out int a, out int b)
        {
            a = r.Next(0,100);
            b = r.Next(0,100);
        }

        OutLocal(out int x, out int y);
        int z = x + y;
    } 

    [Benchmark]
    public void Tuple()
    {
        (int a, int b) TupleLocal() => (r.Next(0,100),r.Next(0,100));

        (int x, int y) = TupleLocal();
        int z = x + y;
    } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<OutVsTuple>();
    }
}
```

Results :

```
 Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
    Out | 27.10 ns | 0.5799 ns | 1.2233 ns |
  Tuple | 28.52 ns | 0.5486 ns | 0.4863 ns |
```

Now the result looks more reasonable.

1. Do compiler has any mechanism to collapse function like I have guessed?
2. Why the tuple function takes time when the result can be easily known like the `out` case?

Ps. After more runs the first case finally returns non-zero, but still very low.

```
 Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
    Out | 0.0022 ns | 0.0080 ns | 0.0075 ns |
  Tuple | 5.0376 ns | 0.1484 ns | 0.1823 ns |
```

Comment: in .NET, this isn't usually a *compiler* function - it is a **JIT** function; the JIT does all sorts of tricks to inline things, but you can disable that with `[MethodImpl(...)]` (there's a no-inlining option); note you'd need to apply this to the *method being called*, which might mean moving them outside of the method as top-level methods rather than local methods.

Comment: Yes, dead code elimination is a standard jitter optimizer feature.  If the code has no observable side-effect then there are decent odds that it will disappear.  It is very conservative however, it doesn't try to get close to solving the Halting Problem.  It won't eliminate constructor calls for example, the reason the tuple code can't be optimized away.  Random.Next() can't be eliminated, it alters the Random object state.  So you are actually measuring Random performance, pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the tuple function takes time when the result can be easily known like the out case?

Here lies your error: the tuple version is actually creating a new instance of the `ValueTuple` struct.

The first version with the `out` parameters is equivalent to two simple assignments to constants.
The tuple version is actually conceptually equivalent to this:

```
var newTuple = new ValueTuple(1, 2);
var a = newTuple.Item1;
var b = newTuple.Item2;
```

and it takes more time because a new instance *has* to be created *at runtime* and thus cannot be optimized away.

You can see that tuples are not constants if you try to use them in a `DataRow`:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow( (1, 2) )]  // won't compile
void SomeTest( (double, double) args ) { }
```

The compiler will complain that you need a constant expressions, and tuples are not.